# modify query to order by case and then view_count

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my current query.

```
Select
    item.*, 
    address_book.Country 
My current query

From
    item 
        Inner Join
    address_book 
        on item.addressbook_id = address_book.idaddress_book
Order By view_count desc,
    Case When address_book.Country='USA' Then 0 Else 1 End 
 limit 100;
```

Currently it just returns it by view_count.

I would like to get back the results first with the biggest view count for the country specified (in this example) USA and then for the rest of the countries (if there are any others  apart from USA).

E.g I would like my result to look like as follows:

```
Name  Description   View_count country
XXX1  XXXX2         120        USA
XXX2  XXXX3         100        USA
XXX4  XXX9          075        USA
XXX3  XXXX4         510        JAPAN
XXX2  XXXX4         310        China
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very close... your country should be the first part of the order by

```
Order By 
   Case When address_book.Country='USA' Then 0 Else 1 End ,
   view_count desc
```